# Amazon Turk - How to create a qualification test that is not requestable and has no test?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, mechanicalturk, mturk

I want to create a qualification test for a survey on Amazon Turk which has no test and is **not requestable**. It should only be grantable by me.

I create the qualification test using the AWS CLI:

```bash
aws mturk create-qualification-type \
  --endpoint-url "https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" \
  --cli-input-json "CONTENT_OF_JSON"
```

This is the JSON I supplied:

```json
{
  "Name": "ExampleTest",
  "Keywords": "test, qualification",
  "Description": "This is an example test.",
  "QualificationTypeStatus": "Active"
}
```

This is the response I get:

```json
{
    "QualificationType": {
        "QualificationTypeId": "3YV...",
        "CreationTime": 1683895085.0,
        "Name": "ExampleTest",
        "Description": "This is an example test.",
        "Keywords": "test, qualification",
        "QualificationTypeStatus": "Active",
        "IsRequestable": true,
        "AutoGranted": false
    }
}
```

In the HIT Type I defined the qualification requirements like this:

```json
  ...
  "QualificationRequirements": [
    {
      "QualificationTypeId": "3YV...",
      "Comparator": "Exists",
      "ActionsGuarded": "Accept"
    }
  ]
```

In the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateQualificationTypeOperation.html) I didn't found an option to set the parameter `IsRequestable` to `false`.

When I look at HITs on the [worker page](https://worker.mturk.com/) I see some HITs that have exactly what I need and I wonder how they did it.